# Categorical variable for Arima

Tags: categorical-data, arima

Does Arima support the usage of categorical variable? 
Some ways to get it working can be using one-hot encoding to represent categorical variables, but I am not sure how good it is.

Comment: It works fine..

Comment: Since ARIMA is a univariate model (there is only one variable and its own lags plus errors and their lags), are you asking whether you can apply ARIMA for a categorical variable?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main types of model: ARIMAX (where the predictors are additional terms in the ARIMA equation), and regression with ARIMA errors. [There is a difference.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) Your software should tell you which one it does (e.g., `forecast::auto.arima()` for R fits a regression with ARIMA errors). If it doesn't, you may be able to deduce it from the modeling output (and I personally might see this as a cause for concern).